Counting number of specific characters in a row (not in a range)
I'm having trouble finding a simple way to count "X"s marked in a row, but in specific columns.
On the left (highlighted in pink), I have various categories of "rope replacement reasons", and on the right, there are columns to log each instance of rope replacements with "X" marking different reasons.
I want to add all instances of "core" marked with X on anchor #1, all "fuzz" marked with X on anchor #1, etc.

Below is the link to the file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B35V6e-boAl8XWPpPuTI6gaMI0CsdOgGHvwrT0a-PQM/edit?usp=drive_link
i'm not sure how to do this..

your sheet is not shared

You can do this using COUNTIFS:
=COUNTIFS($P2:2,"X",$P1:1,F1)


Or as an array formula:
=ARRAYFORMULA(BYROW(P2:ZZZ,LAMBDA(r,IFERROR(1/COUNTIFS(r,"X",P1:1,F1:J1)^-1))))



i ended up using z's countif formula~. works perfectly!

try:
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(P3:3; P3:3="X"; P2:2=F2)))


then you want to do:
=BYCOL(F2:J2; LAMBDA(x; COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(P3:3; P3:3="X"; P2:2=x)))))


and next you want:
=BYROW(P3:50, LAMBDA(y, BYCOL(F2:J2, LAMBDA(x, COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(y, y="X", P2:2=x)))))))


you can add some IF to hide zeros, or you can do:
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/BYROW(P3:50, LAMBDA(y, BYCOL(F2:J2, LAMBDA(x, COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(y, y="X", P2:2=x))))))))))



there does seem to be one minor issue, which is that when there is no "X" marked, the count shows up as '1'.  is there a way to mitigate this?

@ChulhoChang use IFNA from updated answer

i tried using your "=BYROW(P3:50, LAMBDA(y, BYCOL(F2:J2, LAMBDA(x, COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(y, y="X", P2:2=x)))))))" but could not get it to replicate what you end up with.  What I end up with is all subsequent rows with same values as row 3.  any tips?
